# How to make data received from API globally accessible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

what changes shall I make in code so that I can store weather forecast data in `dataset = {};` or What can I do to make forecast data globally accessible?

```
   const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    const https = require("https");
    const { json } = require("express/lib/response");
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    var _ = require('lodash');
    // const unixconvertor = require("./functions");
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    // const convertor = require(__dirname + "/functions.js");
    // const coordinates = [{lat:18.521428 , lon:73.8544541}]
    let dataset = {};
    
    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
      let pagename = "";
      res.render("index",{pagename:pagename});
    })
    //reminder:add code which gives user choice to choose between unit 
    app.post("/", function (req, res) {
      let cityname = req.body.city;        // get data  
      const appid = "xxxxxxxxxx";
      let coordinatelink = "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" + cityname + "&limit=1&appid=" + appid + "";
       fetch(coordinatelink)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          // const coords = [{lat : data[0].lat ,
          // lon : data[0].lon
          // }];
          let lat = data[0].lat;
          let lon = data[0].lon;
          const link = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=" + appid + "&units=metric";
          return fetch(link);
        
    
        })
        .then(responce => responce.json())
        .then(data => {
    
          const sunrise = data.current.sunrise;
          var sunriseDate = new Date(sunrise * 1000);
          var sunriseHours = sunriseDate.getHours();
          var sunriseMinutes = "0" + sunriseDate.getMinutes();
          var sunriseSeconds = "0" + sunriseDate.getSeconds();
          var sunriseFormattedTime = sunriseHours + ':' + sunriseMinutes.substr(-2) + ':' + sunriseSeconds.substr(-2);
          const sunset = data.current.sunset;
          var sunsetDate = new Date(sunset * 1000);
          var sunsetHours = sunsetDate.getHours();
          var sunsetMinutes = "0" + sunsetDate.getMinutes();
          var sunsetSeconds = "0" + sunsetDate.getSeconds();
          var sunsetFormattedTime = sunsetHours + ':' + sunsetMinutes.substr(-2) + ':' + sunsetSeconds.substr(-2);
          // dataset = JSON.stringify(data["data"]);
          dataset.push(JSON.stringify(data));
          
          // res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/"+"cityname+");4
          
          // res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
        }).catch(() => {
          msg.textContent = "Please search for a valid city ";
        });
        
      
    });
    
    app.get("/searchloc",function(req,res){
      //use ejs to embed data and refer to onenote to for editing html
     
      
    })
    
    app.post("/searchloc", function(req,res){
      cityname = req.body.city;
      // let iconurl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+ dataset.current.weather[0].icon+"@2x.png"
      console.log(dataset);
      res.render("searchloc",{cityname:cityname});
      console.log(dataset);
      // icon:iconurl
    })
    
    
    
    
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
      console.log("server created");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like a session variable to achieve this. A global in a Node based HTTP server is global for the server and not the the request. You'd have sessions overwriting each other. Also, you use "let" to declare the dataset variable. Let and const have block scope, whereas var has global scope.

Comment: How can I do it with async and await?